# Linux kernel: build a out-of-tree module that matches the source tree version

Tags: build, module, linux-kernel, version, kernel-module

I need to build a linux kernel module, that must match the version of the tree of my source tree.

When I build the module from inside the source tree, the version number of the module is the one of my source tree. However, when I build it from outside the source tree, using the following makefile, it uses the version of the kernel that is currently running. And I dont know how to make it with the source tree of the kernel.

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
  obj-m := chardriver.o
else
  KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
  PWD  := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif
```

I guess the problem comes from the $(shell uname -r) (because it obviously returns the version of the running kernel, not the version of the source)

Any one knows how to specify the version from out-of-tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the Kernel source tree path of the kernel with which you want to build your module. `make -C` takes the kernel directory path as an argument. The path `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` will use the kernel that you are currently running on. The directory `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` consists of the already built kernel modules which you can use (link) to build your own loadable kernel module. In order to cross-compile your module with a kernel other than the one currently running your Makefile should be something like this:

```
obj-m += chardriver.o

all:
        make -C /Path/to/Kernel/Source/Tree/ M=$(PWD)

clean:
        rm -fr *.o *.order *.mod.c *.mod.o *.ko Module.symvers
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the kernel version or path using the command line (ex: make KERNELDIR=/path/to/dir/), if nothing is being passed use the default running kernel (or just run `make` to pick up the default running kernel), your makefile should looking something like this

```
ifeq ($(KERNELDIR),)
           KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
endif

obj-m += chardriver.o

all:
           $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```